# how to set the DEFAULT system font in android app?

Tags: android, xml

Can I set the default font which is bydefault set in android app irrespective of which font user has selected???

Thanks in advance

Comment: What? Can you explain more..

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to do… Are you trying to set a default font for your app? Are you trying to change the device's font systemwide (forget it), or?

Comment: In your device you can change the system font to Default Font that font I want to use in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a developer there is no easy way to use a specific font in every screen of your app.

You have to set your custom font on each and every UI element. This is explained [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/).
Alternatively you can use this [CustomFont](https://github.com/rulych/Custom-Font-on-Android/blob/master/src/com/rulych/customfont/CustomFont.java) helper class to change every UI elemnt for you.